# Driving two Dell UP2715K monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have been using a Dell UP2715K happily with a Nvidia NVS 510 card.  It drives the screen at full res (5120x2880) and 60Hz refresh without problems, using a pair of DisplayPort cables.  The card is also able to drive two other (single-cable) monitors at the same time .

However, I have not been able to set up two of the Dell UP2715K monitors - neither by plugging them both into the same NVS 510 card, nor by having one card for each.  The second UP2715K will do 3840x2160 only, despite being connected with two DisplayPort cables.  This is with Windows 7 x64 and the latest Nvidia Quadro/NVS drivers (350.12 released 2015-04-14).

Does anyone have a working setup with two 5k monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, an embarassingly simple solution - only one of the two DisplayPort cables was connected, so only 4k resolution was available.  The UP2715K on-screen display shows two DisplayPort icons side by side, but that doesn't necessarily mean that both ports are connected, only that it will try to use both if possible.

So you can successfully drive two UP2715Ks from a single NVS 510 card.

Since posting this question I have installed a second NVS 510 card in the same machine and am driving a third UP2715K from that second card.  I expect that driving four of these monitors would be possible from the same two cards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful list of Nvidia Quadro cards & basic specs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro

The NVS-510 was released in late 2012, and the NVS-810 came out three years later in late 2015, with all the specs being roughly doubled.

The NVS-810 is marketed as being able to run 8x 4k monitors. *"It comes with eight mini-DisplayPort 1.2 connectors. Each can drive true 4K resolution displays that are all synchronized."* https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2015/11/04/digital-signage-nvs-810/

Unfortunately, I've not yet found any reference to MST - but the NVS-810 MAY be able to run 4x 5k monitors. (TBD).

Comment: The list is useful, but the specifications list only what is "supported" by the manufacturer, not what is actually possible.  For example, the card mentioned in the original question, the NVS 510, is shown with a max res of 3840x2160, even though I am using it to drive two 5k monitors without problems.

Comment: You are likely right that the NVS 810 would drive four 5k monitors.  One other thing to note is that multi-stream transport (MST) is not needed for the Dell UP2715K.  It just has two ordinary DisplayPort streams without MST.