# Driving a Dell UP2715K monitor with single NVIDIA NVS 510?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

- **Operating System**: Microsoft Windows 10 x64
- **Display Card: NVIDIA** NVS 510 (4-ports mDP)

I have gone through the following links from a forum, but I could not manage to do it.

[What specs must a graphics card have to power a 5K monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/845302/what-specs-must-a-graphics-card-have-to-power-a-5k-monitor)

Ed Avis said that currently, he is driving two UP2715Ks (5120x2800@60Hz) from a single NVS 510 card ( https://superuser.com/users/137669/ed-avis )

Comment: Have you connected two mDP cables from your PC to the one Dell monitor?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that other thread has been updated. [What specs must a graphics card have to power a 5K monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/845302/what-specs-must-a-graphics-card-have-to-power-a-5k-monitor)

Also, suggest that you view some other threads that address this same question. Eg:
[Driving two Dell UP2715K monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/901372/driving-two-dell-up2715k-monitors/1164470#1164470)

And you might want to consider the NVS-810 card too. It's a more recent & improved release. Thou all of this required MST (2x DP inputs) to run 5k.

Answer (score 0):

check that you have installed the Nvidia drivers and that you are connecting the monitor with the pair of DisplayPort cables (I think it ships with a cable that has two mini-DP connectors at each end).