# Possible to drive 5K display with MacBook Pro + Thunderbolt PCI chassis + Capable Video Card?

Tags: macos, graphics-card, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

It's my understanding that currently the only Mac hardware that specifically supports an outboard 5K display (like [this one](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=up275k3)) is the Mac Pro and that this only came along with the recent 10.10.3 update.

If one were to get an [outboard Thunderbolt PCI expansion chassis](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echoexpressse1.html), and a [video card capable of driving a 5K monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/845302/what-specs-must-a-graphics-card-have-to-power-a-5k-monitor), and [a recent, Thunderbolt-supporting MacBook Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MGXC2LL/A) what are the chances that such a machine could successfully drive such a monitor?

It seems like it should be doable, but I admit that it'd be a LOT of "moving parts" to expect to all work together just right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd contact the manufacturer of that expansion chassis - there is a chance that they have tried that configuration and not put it in the compatibility list (which includes no video output cards at all). *However*, you will need to check that video card driver software is available for the Mac, for example Nvidia do not list Mac display drivers for the NVS 510 but they do make a couple of Quadro cards for Mac.